# Frown (Error) Error Message: "Value does not fall within the expected range." - on ListObjects.Add().QueryTable

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc, syntax-error

I have the following code that uses Microsoft Access Text Drive to join 2 CSV files together. The code works properly if there are no spaces in the filepaths, otherwise errors with message "**Syntax error in FROM Clause**".

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim oCon As New ADODB.Connection, oRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSql$, strCon$, strF1$, strF2$

strF1 = "C:\Users\ADAM\Documents\TEST FOLDER\Names.csv"
strF2 = "C:\Users\ADAM\Downloads\Address.csv"

strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"

strSql = "Select n.*, a.[Address] " & _
            "From " & strF1 & " n " & _
            "INNER JOIN " & strF2 & " a " & _
            "ON n.Name = a.Name "

    oCon.Open strCon
    Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSql)

'    Sheet1.UsedRange.EntireRow.Delete
'    Sheet1.Cells(1).CopyFromRecordset oRs

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim oQT As QueryTable
    Set oQT = Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, oRs, Destination:=Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)).QueryTable
    With oQT
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

But there is another issue which happens when i am adding the QueryTable. Please note, I don't have any Power Queries defined in the workbook:

> Frown (Error)  Error Message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."

I am pasting the entire text below:

```
    Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
Value does not fall within the expected range.

Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeExcelFunctionsBase.ValidateResult(Int32 result, Int32[] expectedValues)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeExcelFunctionsMSI.Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.INativeExcelFunctions.GetConnectionProperties(IntPtr workbookPointer, String connectionName)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeEventHandler.<>c__DisplayClass27.<OnListObjectCreated>b__25()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)

Stack Trace Message:
Value does not fall within the expected range.

Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelCallbackManager.InvokeAndReturnHResult(Action action)


Supports Premium Content:
True
```

Not sure, but somewhere something is amiss! Appreciate anyone's help with a solution to this problem.

Comment: Try to replace one double-quote with three double-quote in strF1, i.e.   
strF1 = """C:\Users\ADAM\Documents\TEST FOLDER\Names.csv"""

Comment: @yu2, tried it, error - `The microsoft database engine could not find the object 'C:\Users\ADAM\Documents\TEST FOLDER\Names.csv'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and path correctly. If 'C:\Users\ADAM\Documents\TEST FOLDER\Names.csv' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.`

Comment: @sifar, Hi, have you solved the Frown Error? I am having the same error when using ListObjects.Add().QueryTable, it is appreciated if you can share the solution if there is any.

Comment: Nope. The only solution is to make sure you don't click on Data > Show Queries in Excel ribbon.